# SBT downloads wrong version of sbt jars

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multimodule project for which I want to activate [cached resolutions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html), which implies that I need to build it with SBT 0.13.7+.

So I've specified `sbt.version=0.13.13` in my `project/build.properties` and `project/project/build.properties` (I have scala code under `project/`).

But after a complete wipe of my `~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt`, I observe the following logs :

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/me/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/me/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/jars/sbt.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13!sbt.jar (2239ms)

// ... etc, downloading everything SBT 0.13.13

[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/me/my-project/project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/me/my-project/project/project/}my-project-build-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/me/my-project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/me/my-project/project/}my-project-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin/0.13.5/jars/scripted-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#scripted-plugin;0.13.5!scripted-plugin.jar (2400ms)

// ... etc, downloading everything SBT 0.13.5

[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/me/my-project/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[error] /Users/me/my-project/project/src/main/scala/my/project/sbt/build/Defaults.scala:41: not found: value updateOptions
[error]     updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

So apparently, SBT tries to build my project definition against the 0.13.5 jars, which is definitely not what I want.

Can someone point me why SBT uses this 0.13.5 version although I have absolutely no reference to it anywhere in my project ?